# Search A database with more than 100 tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I plan to perform a search on a database with more than 100 tables. I UNION all the tables to make the search faster

```
SELECT  `query`,url,keyword , body, title, pagerank, `precision`,Empire FROM  jenniferaniston
WHERE title LIKE '%$q%' OR
body LIKE '%$q%' OR
keyword LIKE '%$q%' OR
`query`LIKE '%$q%' OR
url LIKE '%$q%'
UNION ALL
```

I did the same method for all one hundred tables.  Is there any other way to write a shorter code in MySQL?
because I Faced Errors in Cpanel that I think it might be related to SQL statements.

Comment: Why do I always have to add a comment asking for the error messages?

Answer (score 2):

A `LIKE` expression that starts and ends with `%` wild-card cannot use an index. You want to do it for several columns in a 100-table database. There's simply no way to make it fast: MySQL will basically need to read every single row in your entire database.

Something worries me. If `UNION ALL` is an option that means that your 100 tables share the same structure. Additionally, one of the tables is called `jenniferaniston`. This suggests that your database design is completely denormalised and every time you add data from a new actor you're possibly creating a new table that's essentially a copy of all other tables. Fix that before it's too late! You should have a master table called `actor` and then link it via foreign keys to other tables that contain the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use information_schema database to get a list of tables and make a query using that.

or, you could just dump the whole database and search the file!

Answer (score 0):

You can find with the help of information_schema database.

```
select 
subq.table_schema, subq.numberOfTables
from
(select 
    table_schema, count(table_name) as numberOfTables
from
    tables
group by table_schema) as subq
where
subq.numberOfTables > 100
```